# Sub Categorized Status Choices in Django

Tags: django, django-models

Let's say I have a model of sandwiches, and I want to say what protein you want to put on the sandwich:

```
class Sandwich(models.Model):
    protein_choices = (
        ('n',  'Please Choose'),
        ('e1', 'Eggplant'),
        ('e2', 'Hummus'),
        ('v1', 'Provolone'),
        ('v2', 'Egg'),
        ('p1', 'Fish'),
        ('c1', 'Beef'),
        ('c2', 'Chicken'),
        ('c3', 'Pork'),
    )
    protein = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=protein_choices,
        default='n',
    )
```

How could I make the choices categorized by v`E`gan, `V`egetarian, `P`escatarian, or `C`arnivore?

I want to be able to check its category (is the sandwich Vegan[assuming categorizations don't overlap]?), and I have been using a model.Manager, but I want to ensure that all choices have a single category (I think this is the missing link, and don't think testing is the right way) and only one choice is selected (which is already handled by the status structure presented).

Should this be handled in a `model.Form`, a 1->M relationship with some other structure, or through `model.Manager`s and something else?

Comment: Assuming categories don't overlap? So eggplant will show up in vegetarian, but not vegan? That seems odd.

Comment: I know the problem(s) with this example, but you are now talking about a different issue (no categorization is atomic, hence why it is a categorization/classification).   Try to think of it using any examples you choose :)  BTW, Eggplant is in the v`E`gan category currently, and I think you meant to transpose your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is an in-memory data structure and interface that maps your status keys to their appropriate category. For example you could [use an Enum with a `category` property as the basis for your Choices.](https://hackernoon.com/using-enum-as-model-field-choice-in-django-92d8b97aaa63) If the relationships between those strings ends up being something you want to manage in the database you can always refactor and add a migration.

As you've noted building a tree structure in your models as others have suggested makes for a lot of joins.. and in that case it might be useful to take a look at [django-treebeard](https://github.com/django-treebeard/django-treebeard) or [django-categories](https://github.com/callowayproject/django-categories) and check if it's reasonable to take on that additional dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I think having separate models for protein and category will be good.

**Example**:

```
class Protein(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class ProteinCategory(models.Model):
    protein = models.ForeignKey(to="Protein")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Sandwich(models.Model):
    protein = models.ForeignKey(to="Protein")
```

Use `ManyToManyField` instead of `ForeignKey` in `Sandwich` model, if a `Sandwich` contains many `Protein`.
Use `OneToOneField` in `ProteinCategory` model, if a `Protein` can be in one and only one `ProteinCategory`.

Comment: The question says that only one choice is selected.  Many-to-many is not an option.

Comment: This also doesn't ensure on all choices are in a [single] category

Comment: Every protein that you are adding in the sandwich has a category associated with it. Hence, the `ProteinCategory` model.

Comment: I think I understand, maybe the Foreign keys are misplaced/mixed up and that is what is confusing me.

Comment: Look at it again in reference to the form you are going to present the user with to create sandwiches or adding new proteins with a category.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using different models for this task.

Continuing with your example, you could have the proteins, which each belong to a single category (as per your request in the comments to your question):

```
class ProteinCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Protein(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    category = models.ForeignKey(to=ProteinCategory)
```

Then you could assign a single protein (as per your request) for each sandwich:

```
class Sandwich(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    protein = models.ForeignKey(to=Protein)
```

Does this seem to solve your issue?

Comment: I think this would require 3 join statements now to find out what [sub]category the sandwich is in.   This seems less than elegant, but I am trying to learn what options there are, and this certainly is an option.